# How to reset Dell PowerConnect 2824 switch

Tags: dell, switch, dell-powerconnect

I have the mentioned router and I seam to have somehow removed my ability to access it via the browser...I can connect to it through the serial and it still allows connections through it to the internet but I would like to reset it back to stock so that I can take another go at this.

After connecting to the terminal I found where I can delete these config files (I think) but it asks for the file name, is there some way I can get a list of these config files so that I can delete them? Or is there some other way to restore it to factory settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From first link of Google search: [Dell Power Connect 28XX](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/edocs/network/pc28xx/en/ug/pdf/ug_en.pdf).
There is the chapter Startup Procedures, maybe it is useful.

Comment: Great thanks, the 'manual' that came with the switch was seriously lacking in the information department :)